# White Screen of Death error

Tags: fatal-error

The home page of my [website](http://www.inbreakthrough.tv/) is loading well, but once loaded, it gets refreshed and a white screen is displayed. I tried many solutions, including restoring the database, deactivating plugins, etc, but no success.

Comment: have you enabled debugging to see if you have any errors?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error you are defining `WP_CACHE` as **true** somewhere (maybe in `wp-config.php`?).  This way Wordpress is looking for a file that doesn't exist in default installation.

Disable it and the error will be gone.

You can also create an empty file `advanced-cache.php` in **wp-content/ directory** if you are unable to find `WP_CACHE`

Comment: thanks, i tried it and that error gone but still loading  white page

Comment: I see 2 errors. One is that you have `html.js {display: none;}` in your css which hides whole page. Second error i saw is that your theme is missing `header.php` file sometimes. Looks like something is breaking your theme and this file is not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

thanks friends for all your support.
i tried many things excluding one .js file in my theme.
one .js file created by payment gateway integration team was creating the whole problem. i have just replaced it and site is working fine.